# Localization based on User Profile

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, localization

1) I have a requirement where in I need to change the Language of the site depending on the User who has logged in.

a) How to achieve this? Is it possible to do without Variations? I don't want to change the URL!

b) To get the language of the user should I create a custom field in the Active Directory / Can make use of the Country in the Address Tab of the User in Active Directory?

2). I need to do the similar localization for the web parts. how to achieve this?

Any Ideas?

Also please let me know the best practices for the above.

Grace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msmvps.com/blogs/cobrien/archive/2008/12/08/building-multi-lingual-sharepoint-sites-introducing-the-language-store.aspx

This will probably help you on building multi-lingual page in SharePoint, and it also allows you to change the detection method to fit your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the input James. Can you pl help me on the First part of the Question?

Comment: Grace, have you had chance to look up the link I provided?
Quote from that web site
"
How the Language Store determines which language to retrieve

In the current implementation, the regional settings of the SPWeb are used to determine which translations are retrieved. It's a single method in the code (a single line in fact!), so this scheme could easily be changed if you have a different requirement......"

To answer your question. a) Yes, you can do this without change the URL. b)You can just use the Contry field from AD, no custom field needed

Answer (score 0):

2) You can programmatically retrieve any information from user profile or even the bworser locale (as I do) and show content depending on it.